# Don't convert digits to words after decimal point when using Numbers_Words

Tags: php, pear

I have a script using [`Numbers_Words`](http://pear.php.net/package/Numbers_Words) to spell numerals in words. I want to prevent spelling the words after a decimal point.

For example: for the input `100.25`, I get the output `One hundred & twenty five`, but I want `One hundred & 25`.

How can I do that?

Comment: One hundred and twenty-five, to me, is written as 125 in digits.

Comment: Having said that, I'm not sure when exactly to use and and hyphen (British English).

Comment: Just remove the decimal before translating it. Then you can append the decimal value after the translated word.

Comment: From the README: "With PEAR::Numbers_Words class you can change an integer number to simple words. "  There is no mention of decimals.

Comment: Thank you Progrock, maybe in need to check script php files, not number_words.

Answer (score 0):

As Magnus suggests above, you could separate your number into parts.  Run the integer part through your number to words class, and deal with the mantissa separately.

```
<?php
$numberish = "100.25";
$mantissa  = null;
$int       = floor($numberish);
if (strpos($numberish, '.') !== false)
    $mantissa = end(explode('.', $numberish));

$numberWang = new Number_Words();
echo $numberWang->toWords($int, 'en_GB'), $mantissa ? ' point ' . $mantissa : '';

// Mock version.
class Number_Words
{
    function toWords($int, $lang)
    {
        return 'one hundred';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
one hundred point 25
```

I'd be more inclined to read 100.25 out in English as:

> one hundred point two five.